# game.state is undefined in Phaser 3 (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, phaser-framework

I began coding a game in phaser and while getting the game states ready. It popped up a 'game.state is undefined' type error in the console. Not sure what to do as I've tried whatever I can to try to fix this problem. The code is given below.

The index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Phaser Game</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
 <script src="state1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Main.js file:

```js
const game = new Phaser.Game(600, 400, Phaser.AUTO);
game.State.add('state1', demo.state1);
game.State.start('state1');
```

The state1.js file:

```js
var demo = {};
demo.state1 = function(){};
demo.state1.prototype = {
 preload: function(){},
 create: function(){},
 update: function(){}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't `state` in game object. you should replace it with `scene`.
It's also better to use the standard way to create game object.

```
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    scene:  {
      preload: function(){},
      create: function(){},
      update: function(){}
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

More details can be found on the phaser [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Game.html)
You can Find many useful examples [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v3)